# Tableau: how to create calculated field for previous day value

Tags: field, tableau-api, percentage

I have created a monthly calendar in tableau that tracks enrollment sign ups for a business's rewards program. What I am trying to do is show the day over day % change between enrollment values. In this specific scenario, I am trying to find the % change between 371 to 499. However, to do this, I believe I first need to create a calculated field for the prior days value, so that I can then use the day over day % formula for all other values. Does anyone have any advice for this particular scenario?[image: what I need help with]

I have tried using the datediff function, amongst other calculated fields, with no luck so far. I want to created a calculated field that will retrieve all "enrollment" values but only for the previous day, so that I can then use the "100*((final-initial)/initial) calculation to calculate the day to day % difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function. I think this might be the calc you need.

```
  (ZN(SUM([Distance])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Distance])), -1)) / 
  ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Distance])), -1))
```

[image]

You might have to play with the sign to get the result you want. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: That's still just returning me the same days enrollment value. So on the 25th, it's returning 499, not 371, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: updated the calc to use lookup rather than previous_value

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working either

Comment: can you provide the output of the latest calc? What does it return on the 25th when trying to find the %change from the 24th?

Comment: Nothing is showing up at all when I drag it into the label mark. Im wondering if the calendar format is screwing everything up itself.

Comment: the formula should just take the previous value. I would simplify by starting a new sheet and adding the Enroll field with a date and the above calc and see if it works there. Then you can start discovering what might be blocking it from there by adding to that starting point.